# How may I know the number of same elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following html :

`<div class="same"></div>
<div class="same"></div>`

And I want to print the number of **div** with the id `"same"` like this

`<p><script>document.write(getElementbyId("#same").sum);</script></p>`

And it would print : 2...

It actually doesn't work, I know I don't use the good Javascript function.

Comment: Well, you have a `class` not an `id`. Even if it was an id, that's not the id you searched for with `getElementById("#same")` (seems you're mixing vanilla js and jQuery). You could use `getElementsByClassName` and then check the length of the returned collection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd use `.length` and `.getElementsByClassName()` like this:

```html
<div class="same"></div>
<div class="same"></div>
<p><script>document.write(document.getElementsByClassName("same").length);</script></p>
```